# how to remove .0 when i gave input also in integer

Tags: android

In this code text view for every integer number and decimal number if i give as an input in text box in text view its showing with .0 how to remove that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

      EditText etNum1;
      EditText etNum2;

      Button btnAdd;
      Button btnSub;
      Button btnMult;
      Button btnDiv;

      TextView tvResult;

      String oper = "";

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // find the elements
        etNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
        etNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum2);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnMult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMult);
        btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);

        tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        // set a listener
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        btnSub.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnMult.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);

      }
  @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         double  num1=0;
         double num2=0;
         double result=0;


        // check if the fields are empty
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum1.getText().toString())
            || TextUtils.isEmpty(etNum2.getText().toString())) {
         return;
        }

        // read EditText and fill variables with numbers

        num1 = Double.parseDouble(etNum1.getText().toString());
       num2 = Double.parseDouble(etNum2.getText().toString());



        // defines the button that has been clicked and performs the corresponding operation
        // write operation into oper, we will use it later for output
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
          oper = "+";

         result = num1 + num2;

          break;
        case R.id.btnSub:
          oper = "-";
          result = num1 - num2;

          break;
        case R.id.btnMult:
          oper = "*";
          result = num1 * num2;

          break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
          oper = "/";
         result = num1 / num2;

          break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        // form the output line


        String text=String.valueOf(result);
        String str[]= text.split(".");

        tvResult.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + str[1]);

      }
    }
```

Comment: @FD_ - Just edit the question!

Comment: @PreetSangha Sorry, will do that next time.

Comment: bad idea to split decimal with .(dot)

Comment: @KamleshArya depends on the locale.

Comment: Your original question was closed as a duplicate - try the solutions in the linked question before opening a new question. If they don't work/apply, explain **why** that is so in your original question and flag it asking for it to be reopened. Do not just open additional questions when you don't get the answer you want or it isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the decimal places, just use

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

in your code.

Otherwise, you can use `String.format()` to format the string to display 0 decimal places:

```
String.format("%.0d", yourDouble)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @FD_ that's a useful regex for me, despite the... long winded, shoutey question asked, your answer is helpful, thanks!

Comment: @RossC For reference, that's a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), not a regex :p

Comment: @thegrinner Thanks for that, I haven't seen it before, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply Replace your last lines

```
String text=String.valueOf(result);
String str[]= text.split(".");
tvResult.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + str[1]);
```

with

```
tvResult.setText(num1 + " " + oper + " " + num2 + " = " + Integer.parseInt(result));
```